# Printing NSData in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do you output the value of `NSData` in **Swift**? Is it `NSLog`, `print` or `println`?

It seems I can just print the address of the object, and not the actual contents of it.

Thank-you

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So after trying a number of recommendations around the site, this is what actually ended up working for me.

**Swift 3**

```
let string1 = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Data could not be printed"
print(string1)
```

**Swift 1**

```
let string1 = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(string1)
```

Comment: This works without the NS prefix in Swift 2.3 In my case, `data` is optional so I'm using: `print(String(data: data ?? NSData(), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))`

Comment: Only works with legal ascii codes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866935/nsdata-to-string-in-swift-issues

Answer (score 4):

Try `NSString`

```
let theString:NSString = NSString(data: someNSData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
println(theString)
```

---

*Reference*

```
convenience init(data: NSData, encoding: UInt)
```

Comment: `Extra argument 'data' in call`

Comment: @macdonjo no way, it uses `convenience init(data: NSData, encoding: UInt)`. Check that you have proper configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the bytes (and don't know, or there isn't an appropriate string encoding) you can still use NSLog in swift:

```
NSLog("%@", NSData(bytes: [0x1b], length:1))
```