# bytes convert to string swift (or swift2)

Tags: swift, swift2

I am new in swift. i have this bytes:

> Bytes: [11, 143, 102, 88, 132, 238, 0, 156, 100, 166, 72, 98, 226, 109, 51, 196, 124, 124, 207, 252, 204, 129, 233, 209, 112, 127, 66, 177, 37, 141, 169, 158, 122, 74, 215, 103, 13, 128, 74, 81, 221, 46, 219, 145, 107, 131, 90, 246, 37, 212, 91, 237, 32, 138, 74, 147, 238, 40, 182, 158, 12, 124, 197, 17, 92, 24, 184, 44, 150, 127, 147, 161, 175, 186, 227, 4, 248, 44, 21, 83, 0]

and i used this code:

```
let dencryptedBytes: [UInt8] = try! AES(key: UrlManager.CONNECTION_KEY, iv:UrlManager.CONNECTION_IV, blockMode: .CBC).encrypt(bytes)
```

and result like this:

> Decoded Bytes: [157, 29, 111, 190, 188, 31, 233, 140, 152, 67, 196, 83, 214, 238, 232, 184, 101, 149, 45, 184, 155, 85, 184, 69, 155, 173, 196, 145, 123, 54, 238, 243, 34, 178, 190, 129, 106, 11, 26, 147, 19, 207, 204, 162, 142, 81, 6, 24, 21, 93, 80, 134, 247, 151, 83, 79, 214, 134, 80, 222, 10, 196, 64, 247, 53, 194, 195, 207, 230, 79, 215, 134, 87, 32, 37, 100, 82, 125, 59, 41, 235, 36, 144, 171, 64, 247, 195, 12, 115, 194, 124, 243, 109, 84, 44, 155]

but i need convert this bytes to string. i can not find answer. please advise me.
Thanks a lot !

**Edit:**

I found this:

```
var bytes: [UInt8] = [157, 29, 111, 190, 188, 31, 233, 140, 152, 67, 196, 83, 214, 238, 232, 184, 101, 149, 45, 184, 155, 85, 184, 69, 155, 173, 196, 145, 123, 54, 238, 243, 34, 178, 190, 129, 106, 11, 26, 147, 19, 207, 204, 162, 142, 81, 6, 24, 21, 93, 80, 134, 247, 151, 83, 79, 214, 134, 80, 222, 10, 196, 64, 247, 53, 194, 195, 207, 230, 79, 215, 134, 87, 32, 37, 100, 82, 125, 59, 41, 235, 36, 144, 171, 64, 247, 195, 12, 115, 194, 124, 243, 109, 84, 44, 155]


    print(bytes2String(bytes))

func bytes2String(array:[UInt8]) -> String {
return NSString(data: NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
```

}

link: [NSData to String in Swift Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866935/nsdata-to-string-in-swift-issues)

but it don't work Why is it ?

**Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: Your bytes array contain plenty of unprintable characters. How do you want to deal with them?

Comment: @Zoff Dino, if convert this bytes to string, it will be string like json

Comment: What character does 29 map to? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: i must get like this result: {"res":"connect","hash":"4930022e2d524cc3bdef0a7706468251","state":"complete"}

Comment: What encoding scheme is this? The first double quote is 29, but the second is 31, the third one is 140? Also, your array has 96 bytes but your expected string has only 78 characters.

Comment: I used to encode and decode this link: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94470/discussion-between-clever-and-zoff-dino).

Comment: your bytes are invalid and not a valid string it seems :) this has nothing to do with swift :/

Answer (score 2):

try this

(str=String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

Comment: where is this defined?

Answer (score 1):

if the input data doesn't represent utf8 encoding string NSString constructor failed and return nil. if you unwrap nil value, the result is runtime error.

```
NSString(data: NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

it means exactly, that array `bytes: [UInt8]` is not representable as uft8 string. if i understand, you play with some crypto framework. are you sure that the framework does correct encryption, decryption? make some test first ...